# C++: Declare, define and call function which returns object of template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I am using template to implement a modal class in C++ that stores value of any type.All implementation is in same file. This modal class `CConfigProperty`(template class) is having two variables value`DefaultValue` and type of value it stores `DataType`. In another class `CDefaultConfig` I am having a std::map which will store object of this class. To do this I have created one method which returns object of template class. I am getting two complilation errors in this implementation.I am using Xcode.

> 1 Field has incomplete type 'CDefaultConfig::DefaultValue'
>
> 2 No matching member function for call to 'SetStringValueforModal'

I am not sure how to return object of template class from another function. Also how to use template declared in one class to another class.

Below is the sample source code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return 0;
}


typedef enum CONFIG_DATA_TYPE {

    TYPE_INT = 0,
    TYPE_STRING = 3,
}DataType;

template <class DefaultValue>
class CConfigProperty
{

public:
    CConfigProperty(DataType type,
                    DefaultValue configProperty
                    );
    CConfigProperty();
    ~CConfigProperty(void);
private:
    DataType    m_type;
    DefaultValue  m_configProperty;  /**/Field has incomplete type 'CDefaultConfig::DefaultValue'**
};
```

**Field has incomplete type 'CDefaultConfig::DefaultValue while declaring DefaultValue  m_configProperty;**

```
template <class DefaultValue>
CConfigProperty<DefaultValue>::CConfigProperty(DataType type, DefaultValue configProperty)
:m_type(type),
m_configProperty(configProperty)
{

}

template <class DefaultValue>
CConfigProperty<DefaultValue>::CConfigProperty()
{

}

template <class DefaultValue>
CConfigProperty<DefaultValue>::~CConfigProperty(void)
{
}


class CDefaultConfig
{

public:
    CDefaultConfig();
    ~CDefaultConfig(void);
private:
    void PopulateDefaultConfigForAllKeys(void);
    void printText();

    template <class DefaultValue>
    CConfigProperty<DefaultValue> *SetStringValueforModal(std::string theValue);
};


CDefaultConfig::CDefaultConfig(void)
{
    PopulateDefaultConfigForAllKeys();
}

CDefaultConfig::~CDefaultConfig(void)
{
}

template <class DefaultValue>
CConfigProperty<DefaultValue> * CDefaultConfig::SetStringValueforModal(std::string theValue)
{

    CConfigProperty<std::string> *theConfigProperty = new  CConfigProperty<std::string>(TYPE_STRING,theValue);
    return theConfigProperty;
}

void CDefaultConfig::PopulateDefaultConfigForAllKeys(void)
{
    printText();
    std::map<std::string, CConfigProperty<class DefaultValue> *> Properties;

     Properties["Test"]=SetStringValueforModal("10"); //No matching member function for call to 'SetStringValueforModal

}
```

**No matching member function for call to 'SetStringValueforModal while calling SetStringValueforModal**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to use the

```
std::map<std::string, CConfigProperty<class DefaultValue> *> Properties;
```

like you seem to intend.

The problem is that you need to use concrete types like @Arcathor wrote in his answer:

```
std::map<std::string, CConfigProperty<int> *> Properties;
std::map<std::string, CConfigProperty<std::string> *> Properties;
```

**but**, because `CConfigProperty<int>` is a completely different type than `CConfigProperty<std::string>` from a compiler perspective, you will not be able to use both types mixed in one `std::map`.

What you are doing is **compile time polymorphism**, when you would need **runtime polymorphism**.
You need to add a non-templated base class, and derive `CConfigProperty<>` from it, such that you can use the base class pointer in the `map`.